# Why is it "not necessary to free the resources loaded using LoadResource" for 32-bit Windows applications?

Tags: winapi

In [FreeResource function - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freeresource):

> [This function is obsolete and is only supported for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows. **For 32-bit Windows applications, it is not necessary to free the resources loaded using LoadResource.** If used on 32 or 64-bit Windows systems, this function will return FALSE.]

Why is that? Is it because that the memory is large?

Comment: It's because handles to resources and other types are much more available, and because when the application closes Windows will free those resources for you anyway. As good practice, however, I sill make sure to free all resources I allocate, so that any leaks that are noted meant here's an issue.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you. In my program there are some resources which are not needed after initialization, and I would like to free them in order to save memory.

Comment: @Ken Not true. In 16 bit Windows LoadResource resulted in allocations that needed to be balanced by deallocations. In Win32 the resources are mapped and LoadResource does not involve any allocations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's the point - the resource files are mapped into the memory. I didn't that, now I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specialized resource-specific functions like `LoadBitmap()` "post-process" the actual resource into a usable GDI object, which consumes both additional memory and a slot in the system-wide GDI table ([limited to 64K handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects)). Because of that, it is necessary to call `DeleteObject()` once done with the `HBITMAP` in order to release the associated resources.

Unlike `LoadBitmap()` (and unlike 16-bit Windows), `LoadResource()` does not allocate any additional resources in Win32, but rather "points" to the resource in the memory-mapped image of the already loaded module. Therefore, there is nothing for `FreeResource()` to clean up in Win32.

Quoting from Raymond Chen's [What's the difference between FreeResource and, say, DestroyAcceleratorTable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110307-00/?p=11283):

> In 16-bit Windows, loading a resource entailed allocating a chunk of memory, then filling that memory block from the disk image. In Win32, resources are mapped into the address space as part of the image; there is no memory allocation and no explicit loading.